# Setting up a project in old versions of Ionic and Cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I opt for a course on Udemy (Ionic 3 Apps for WooCommerce: Build an eCommerce Mobile App) in this course tutor is using ionic@2.2.2 and cordova@6.5.0, and now at present time everything is just changed in both Ionic and Cordova.

So I installed an older version of Ionic and Cordova but when I'm creating project in older version I'm getting errors while creating project. And new version everything is changed, can't work on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to get [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm), if you are using windows, try [this](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows).
Thereafter, install an old version of node possibly node version 7 or 8 would do, and then would work as expected.

To install old version do the following:

```
nvm install 8.0.0
nvm use 8.0.0
```

And then remove node_modules if it already exist (possibly by doing an `rm -rf node_modules`)

Then do an `npm install` again :)